# AWS DOC DB query returning null

Tags: java, database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am trying to fetch a document from AWS doc db but getting null pointer. Same query works well in my other lower env. I checked the indexes and they look fine. Below is my code for the same

```
public Query getDetails(String uuid) {
  return new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(uuid)));
}

public Document getTheInfo(String uuid) {
return mongoTemplate.findOne(getDetails(uuid), Document.class, "Record");
}
```

My uuid is in this format uuid = "123-67789-abc-57990".

What's wrong in the above code?

Comment: Can you show us the full stack trace, please?

Comment: Check also this: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)